# AddThis Share Icon not showing at html page

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

Hi I want to add share icon button using AddThis Site

I have added this code to my html page but no icon is showing

Please help...

Comment: Provide more and relevant info. Enviroment, language, some example code, some fiddle example... anything.  Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Check script link in first block, javascript is not loading properly and add `http:` before //, hope it will work.

Comment: The `double slash` without the `http:|https:` prefix is on purpose, leave it like that. Further reading: The [Protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). (you will only need to force `http` protocol if you're opening your file in a local environment)

Comment: When double slash is not working with it, you need to declare it explicitly whether it's http or https, I have found that it's working perfectly. If anyone uses secure link, he needs to add https and otherwise http.